# Tagging questions about Python Add-Ins

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the tags [add-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-in) (78 questions) and [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) (8 questions). Some ArcGIS Python add-in questions are marked with one or the other, and a few are marked with both.

Should [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) be made a [synonym](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/add-in/synonyms) of [add-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-in)?

I have suggested that it should.

To me the [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) tag is redundant because we have the [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, which enables Python syntax highlighting, and the [add-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-in) tag, which in the context of the [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag and an ArcGIS-specific tag such as[arcgis-10.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.1) or [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) indicates that we're talking about ArcGIS Python Add-Ins.

Also, ArcGIS Add-Ins can be written in other languages, such as .NET or Java. But no one has felt the need to create a language-specific tag for those.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) is unnecessary because it reflects the conjunction of two (or three) other tags.

Comment: Is it hypocritical of me to have created the `data-model` tag when we already have both the `data` and `model` tags? :) I think it's an important concept in GIS and deserves its own tag, even though it is a conjunction of existing tags. There is also the `database-model` tag but this is a significantly different concept.

Comment: @blah238 To me, "data" and "model" cover different territory than "data-model."  (Others might disagree.) There is no hypocrisy in creating separate tags for conjunctions that have new meanings, just as [tag:hot] + [tag:dog] does not mean [tag:hot-dog], [tag:fire] + [tag:fly] does not mean [tag:fire-fly], and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to agree with @whuber, but I wonder if in this case we would want to make it easier for a user with limited time, but with high expertise in python addins, to monitor questions by entering `python-addin` into the "Favorite Tags" panel.

If that user enters `python` and `addin` as separate favorite tags, the signal to noise ratio is much lower.

Comment: I'll admit to never using the favorite tags feature, so I didn't think of that. Still, you could always search for multiple tags, e.g. `[python] [add-in]`. There is even an RSS feed for such searches: http://gis.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python+add-in&sort=newest

Comment: this could be a feature request to SE (highlight `[python]+[add-in]` but not merely `[python]` or `[add-in]` on their own (admittedly the uptake on feature requests is low).

Answer (score 2):

I think it was probably me who coined [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) as a tag, and I may also be the main user of it.

[@KirkKuykendall](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3033/115) has hit on how I use it in my Favorites.

I have not been using RSS feeds to search for categories of questions like [@blah238 suggests](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3033/115).

Rather than synonymizing [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) with [addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addin) I would prefer to see [addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addin) renamed to be [arcmap-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap-addin).

Comment: Didn’t you make a radical change in your answer? It should be another answer; this way one does not highjack 3 upvotes from synonymizing to renaming.

Comment: @AndreSilva it’s my own answer and editing it allows voters to remove/reverse their votes if they disagree with its latest revision.

Comment: It is unlikely voters will return to re-evaluate their votes after 6 years and a half.

Comment: @AndreSilva True, but there are only three users with upvotes on it and this answer is far from achieving an implementable vote. My position changed from going along with to stating that I think there’s a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we are either waiting for a mod to approve the [synonym suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/add-in/synonyms) or for users of the tag to [**vote**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/add-in/synonyms) on the synonym suggestion. Anyone with an answer score of 5 in the [add-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-in) tag can vote on it, so maybe we should! At least I think this is how the system is supposed to work. Maybe people just don't know about it!

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

[Synonym voting http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7360/9953b31e2195412298e91b5.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7360/9953b31e2195412298e91b5.png)

Comment: Add-in's don't have to be python based so I'm not entirely sure `python-addin` should be a synonym.

Comment: add-in would be the master tag, python-addin would be merged into it.

Comment: No one has created a c#-addin or java-addin tag or I would suggest those be synonyms as well. Note I am not suggesting anyone create those tags. Please don't :)

Comment: ...in the course of time if we do get enough questions for c#-addin, and that is added as a synonym, filtering for `add-in` will show python-addin too, and thus be broken. However, in true YAGNI spirit, let's wait for that to be a problem before we build a bridge for it.

Comment: It would not be "broken". It would simply fall under the general-purpose `add-in` tag, like it should. Language tags such as `c#` and `python` can and should be used appropriately (as they enable syntax highlighting and facilitate exactly this kind of searching/filtering) and not be duplicated in other tag names, IMO.

Comment: Here is an example from Meta StackOverflow that supports my case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125981

Comment: I'm not making the case for `python-addin` to be kept, I don't think it should exist, for the same reasons explored in the MetaSO discussion. Similarly I don't see the utility of a combo tag synonym: if it existed searching by tag `[python-addin]` would not return the same results as `[python] [addin]`. It would return everything tagged `[addin]`.

Comment: If synonyms can be made as shortcuts for tag combos, `python-addin` a synonym for `python + addin`, that would be something else (not really much less typing though)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am not sure what else could be done other than outright deleting the tag (which you would only want to do after the synonym has been created so that questions with the `python-addin` tag at least end up with the `addin` tag and not nothing. The synonym system solves the main problem -- having a leftover tag does not seem like a major concern, especially considering you can additionally filter by the `python` tag to get the results you want.

Comment: Still, I am somewhat surprised that the synonym suggestion has still gotten 0 votes.

Comment: Here is another Meta StackOverflow discussion about your concern: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88554/should-tag-synonyms-work-for-conjunctions-of-tags Unfortunately it does not appear to have been answered.

Answer (score -1):

This still seems to be [undecided](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/add-in/synonyms), however given that we only have a maximum of 5 tags per question to work with, I think it is more important to use one of those for language-specific tags for questions about or containing code, to enable syntax highlighting and language-specific searches.

So I [edited the tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/58702/revisions) on [a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58702/753) to replace [python-addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-addin) and with [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and [add-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-in). What do you think? Is this appropriate?